# Which is correct method to compare two dates in PHP?

Tags: date, php

I've following code to compare two dates in PHP,which one while be appropriate method

```
<?php 
$var = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('29-05-2012'));
$var1 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('27-06-2012'));

echo $var;    //29-05-2012
echo $var1;   //27-06-2012
if($var1 >= $var) //method 1
 {
  echo 'var1 is future date';
 }
 if(strtotime($var1) >= strtotime($var)) //method 2
 {
 echo 'var1 is future date(second if)';
 }
 ?>
```

In above two methods,method-1 is not working,is it not a correct way to compare two dates in PHP ?

Comment: did you try comparing the dates in Y-m-d format instead

Answer (score 3):

No, the first method is incorrect because `$var1` and `$var` are strings, so you can't compare them like that.

However, strtotime() creates unix timestamps (integers), so you can and should compare them like that.

Comment: but in some cases method-1 is working properly,may I know what might be the reason?

Comment: Thats because when comparing using `>=`, it gets converted to an integer, so something like `29052012` and `27062012`. However, in this case, the problem is that the first integer is bigger though the second date is later.

Answer (score 3):

Just leave the date as string, and convert with `strtotime` in `if ()`.

```
$a = '29-5-2012';
$b = '27-6-2012';

if (strtotime($a) >= strtotime($b)) {
    echo "$a is future date.";
} else {
    echo "$b is future date.";
}

// 27-6-2012 is future date.
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you php version >= 5.3 you can try **[date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = strtotime('29-05-2012'); # <--- past
$time2 = strtotime('27-06-2012'); # <--- future

echo max($time1,$time2);
echo "<br />";
echo min($time1,$time2);
```

Comment: Forgot you wanted to compare dates, so that's probably not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
if (mktime(0,0,0,12,31,2012) > mktime(0,0,0,6,25,2011)) {
   echo "12/31/2012 is after 6/25/2011";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1=date('d/m/y');
$tempArr=explode('_', '31_12_11');
$date2 = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $tempArr[1], $tempArr[0], $tempArr[2]));
```